# Vector in kernel of all linear functionals must be $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a vector space over a field $K$. Suppose that $e\in E$ is such that $\forall f\in \mathcal L(E,K)$, $f(e)=0$. Then prove that $e=0$.

Elements of $\mathcal L(E,K)$ need not be continuous. This is claimed in the Remark following Definition 3.2 in Fabian's *Banach Space Theory*. I quote "[it] follows from a simple linear algebra argument".

What is this "simple linear algebra argument" they are alluding to ?
With the axiom of choice, one could define a basis $(b_i)_{i\in I}$ of $E$ and the corresponding coordinate functionals $f_i$. Then obviously $e=0$.

Is there a simpler argument, preferably something that doesn't resort to choice ?

Comment: Maybe that you want to prove that $e=0$ ?

Comment: @EmilioNovati yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Choice is unavoidable anyway in fields like functional analysis. Maybe instead write $E = \langle e \rangle \oplus V$ with $V$ a subspace of $E$ supposing $e \neq 0$. Then, the map $f(ae+bv) = a$ for $a,b \in K$ and $v \in V$ is linear. I'm not sure at the moment however if you need AoC somewhere in this argument.

Comment: The idea is simple: Were $e$ not $0$, then one could define a linear map sending $e$ to something non-trivial.

Comment: @QiZhu:  That's more or less what I tried to do in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows what might be called a "simple linear algebra argument" provided we allow its use of choice (in the form of Zorn's lemma) is "simple"; in any event, I don't see how "choice $\equiv$ Zorn's" can be avoided here.

If we can prove that, for any

$0 \ne e \in E \tag 1$

there exists a subspace

$V \subset E \tag 2$

such that

$E = \langle e \rangle \oplus V, \tag 3$

then we may define a functional

$f:E \in \mathscr L (E, K)  \tag 4$

*via*

$f(e) = \alpha \in K, \; \alpha \ne 0, \tag 5$

$f(ke) = k \alpha, \; k \in K, \tag 6$

$f(v) = 0, \; v \in V; \tag 7$

we note that (5) affirms that

$f(e) \ne 0;  \tag 8$

thus, as long as (1)-(3) bind, we may assert that

$\exists f \in \mathscr L(E, K), \; f(e) \ne 0.  \tag 9$

We proceed to prove the existence of a subspace $V$ satisfying (3).  Let $\mathscr  V$ be the collection of subspaces of $E$ such that

$W \in \mathscr V \Longleftrightarrow e \notin W; \tag{10}$

$\mathscr V$ is clearly partially ordered by set inclusion, and if we have a chain

$\mathscr C \subset \mathscr V, \tag{11}$

that is,

$X, Y \in \mathscr C \Longrightarrow X \subset Y \; \text{or} \; Y \subset X, \tag{12}$

then

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{W \in \mathscr C} W \tag{13}$

is clearly an upper bound for $\mathscr C$; thus by [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) there is a maximal element $V \in \mathscr V$; I claim such a $V$ satisfies (3).  For if not,

$\langle e \rangle \oplus V \subsetneq E, \tag{14}$

so

$\exists \eta \in E, \eta \notin \langle e \rangle \oplus V; \tag{15}$

then

$\eta \notin V, \tag{16}$

and hence

$V \subsetneq \langle \eta \rangle \oplus V; \tag{17}$

furthermore

$e \notin \langle \eta \rangle \oplus V, \tag{18}$

lest

$e = s\eta + v, \; s \in K, v \in V \tag{19}$

with

$s \ne 0 \tag{20}$

lest

$e \in V; \tag{21}$

in light of (19) and (20) we may write

$\eta = s^{-1}(e - v) \in \langle e \rangle \oplus V, \tag{22}$

which contradicts (15); hence (17) and (18) both hold and together they imply that $V$ is not maximal in the set $\mathscr V$ of subspaces not containing $e$, contradicting its construction *via* Zorn's; this contradictions in fact implies that $V$ satisfies (3), and hence (9) binds as well; thus we must have

$e = 0 \tag{23}$

if

$\forall f \in \mathscr L(E, K), \; f(e) = 0. \tag{24}$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: If you‘re already using Zorn‘s Lemma, the assertion $E = \langle e \rangle \oplus V$ immediately follows by taking a basis containing $e$, doesn‘t it? Of course the standard proof for the existence of such a basis usually uses Zorn‘s Lemma.

Comment: @QiZhu:  I just didn't feel like talking about a basis when I wrote this but of course you are right!  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Some choice is needed, since it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ to have a nontrivial vector space $V$ such that $V^\ast=\{0\}$, and I'm talking about the algebraic dual here.

With choice given $e\in V$ with $e\neq 0$ it's easy to come up with a functional which is not zero on $e$: extend $\{e\}$ to a basis $\{e\}\cup\{v_i\mid i<\kappa\}$ of $V$ and define $\phi:V\to\Bbb R$ by $\phi(e)=1$ and $\phi(v_i)=0$ for every $i$. Extend by linearity to the whole space.

Note that in the context of Banach spaces we can even come up with a continuous functional which is nonzero on $e$, by using Hahn-Banach to extend the functional $\phi\colon\langle e\rangle\to\Bbb R$ given by $\phi(ae)=a$ to a bounded functional on the whole space.